# Translate a formula into VBA

Tags: excel, vba

does anyone know how to translate this formula `=RIGHT(C1,LEN(C1)-SEARCH(":",C1))` into a VBA syntax? I want to use this formula on my excel C column, each cell contains a `":"`. I just want to remove the content before `":"`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `=RIGHT(RANGE("C1").Value,LEN(RANGE("C1").Value)-INSTR(RANGE("C1").Value,":"))`

Comment: `= Mid(value, InStr(1, value, ":") + 1)`

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you! it works!

Comment: @ScottCraner - but if you use that in VBA, won't it not let you due to the single quotes?

Comment: @BruceWayne it is a vba formula, not worksheetfunction.

Comment: @ScottCraner - I think I confused myself. Does my answer get to his question, or am I misunderstanding what he's asking for?

Comment: @BruceWayne It can be read either way

Comment: @ScottCraner - no to belabor the point, but you *don't* need double quotes (`If(a1<>"""",...)`) in VBA when not using a worksheet function?

Comment: @BruceWayne the whole line would be something like `Range("A1") = RIGHT(RANGE("C1").Value,LEN(RANGE("C1").Value)-INSTR(RANGE("C1").Value,":"))`.  It is using vba not worksheetfunctions.  vba has the right, mid and left. The FIND and SEARCH are replaced with INSTR() in vba.  Put something in C1 of an active sheet, something that has a `:` in it somewhere, then type `? RIGHT(RANGE("C1").Value,LEN(RANGE("C1").Value)-INSTR(RANGE("C1").Value,":"))` in the immediate window, it should give you the `:` and everything to the right of it..

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to figure it out is to turn on the macro recorder, then enter your formula.  Then you can check the macro for the result.  Your issue is mainly that you need to use two quotes back to back in VBA, to reflect one quote in the formula bar.

That being said - to avoid R1C1 style, you'd do `Cells(1,1).Formula = "=RIGHT(C1,LEN(C1)-Search("":"",C1))"`

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what you want to do with the result

Userdefined Function =mid(c1,find(":",c1))

but

VBA  = mid(range("C1"),instr(Range("C1"),":"))

Answer (score 1):

Declare a function in a `Module` as

```
Public Function RemoveBeforeColon(ByVal s As String) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    i = InStr(1, s, ":")
    If i > 0 Then
        RemoveBeforeColon = Mid(s, i + 1)
    Else
        RemoveBeforeColon = s
    End If
End Function
```

and use it with a string or a range

```
Debug.Print RemoveBeforeColon("ABC:123")
```

or

```
Debug.Print RemoveBeforeColon( Sheet1.Range("C1").Value2 )
```